# Wordpress Ajax Posting from App

Tags: plugins, ajax, iphone, third-party-applications, android

I am working on an App for a University radio station that allows users to listen to the station and read stories from there wordpress site. I can do this functionality easy enough using RSS feeds.

An additional piece of functionality required is for users to be able to post comments/feedback live to the DJ. Is there anyway of doing this? My thought was using an AJAX comment plugin and designing the app to fake the AJAX call to post the comment, posting the comment to a different page depending on which DJ is on air at the moment.

Any thoughts? Anyone had experience with this kind of thing?

Comment: where will the user being viewing the stories?

Comment: The intention would be for people who view the player as well as people who are using the app to be able to view a relatively live stream of comments. A comment system that allows cross site ajax calls and provides an RSS feed of comments should do the job. Twitter/Facebook integration would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

If you just add a player to the blog maybe in custom temple(page) you can just use an ajax comments plugin and have the DJ have the comments stream open think about using http://disqus.com/